# Chrome behaves differently on different computers

Tags: google-chrome

I have developed (hardware and software) a product which uses an STM microcontroller. It contains an embedded web server which offers web based configuration. The network stack uses a MTU of 700 bytes and only allows one HTTP connection at a time to the server -- uses HTTP 1.0 protocol. One of the configuration selections uses a page that has very large HTML file and a very large js file along with a JQuery.js file (also several other HTML, CSS, and js files).

I use Chrome's "debugger" and wireshark to troubleshoot the issue.

Chrome would always timeout before all the files were downloaded - so I implemented E-Tag and Cache-Control to minimize the amount of data that needed to be downloaded. Note: All the HTML, CSS, and js files are static - stored in EE and downloaded - NO dynamic file content used.

I first used "Cache-Control: no-cache". On MY development system (WIN10) Chrome behaved as expected - once the file was fully downloaded - Chrome would include "If-None-Match:" in the GET request header along with the proper E-Tag. I would reply with "HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified" in the reply header and the page would be then properly presented (Note: First time NEW Page files were required to be downloaded - Chrome would always time out -- then tell Chrome Chrome to refresh the page and the E-Tags would allow Chrome to use its cashe version). I did this to make sure Chrome would do a E-Tag check on every file so as I updated my EE Web file versions - Chrome would always use the latest.

My development computer worked every time as would MOST of my customer's computers.

I have ONE customer (WIN11 - SAME version of Chrome that I use) where Chrome NEVER included "If-None-Match:" in its GET header -- so my customer NEVER could get the page to load.

Any ideas as to WHY?

I changed my GET reply to "Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate". On MY development system (after initial page load completed) Chrome would GET the initial HTML page file and include "If-None-Match:" in the header - I responded with a 304 and then Chrome would complete the page by never asking for the other files - just taking them from its cashe.

On my customer's computer -- Chrome ALWAYS issues a GET for the initial file and did NOT include "If-None-Match:" in its header -- so I had to download the complete file -- Chrome would then use its cash for the remaining files.

Any ideas as to WHY Chrome refuses to issue "If-None-Match:" on any of its GET requests?

Comment: Does the ONE customer use a proxy server?

Comment: No - Web Server is Local to his network.  His computer is connecter to his router - router to switch - switch to my controller.